# Does Shh.. sound help kids to urinate?

Tags: children, urine

It may be an old wives tale (http://www.city-data.com/forum/health-wellness/626346-why-does-sound-feel-water-make.html). Is there any truth to it? Need definitive sources.

Comment: To mitigate link rot, please quote the actual claim.

Comment: @gerrit claim is in the title. anyway, i have voted to close as duplicate exists (but a scientific reason is not given in answer to that other question also)